# Why is Tyler Durden shown with yellow gloves?

Tags: plot-explanation, fight-club

In this image from the movie [*Fight Club*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Club)…

[image: Tyler Durden wearing a yellow glove.]

…we see Tyler Durden (Brad Pitt) wearing yellow gloves.

In this scene he just had sex with Marla Singer (Helena Bonham Carter). My question is: **Why the heck is he wearing yellow gloves?**

I know about a fan theory which postulates:

> Marla is another personality of the main character (Edward Norton), so he is basically masturbating.

I think that nothing in this movie nothing is random, or just a joke, so I am curious.

Comment: If you go to page 122 (third column, 1st paragraph) of [this interview](http://nevpierce.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Fight-Club-Making-Of-Nev-Pierce.pdf)  with Totalfilm, you'll see that this fan-theory isn't accurate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In-universe, this is the sexual equivalent of the "[You do NOT want to know](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouDoNotWantToKnow)" trope. The implication is that he's been doing something *unspeakably kinky and weird* to Marla (something which caused her to scream in ecstasy) and **no further explanation is given**. You're basically expected to leave it to your own dirty imagination to work it out.

Notably the incident doesn't appear in either the source book or the shooting script.

---

Out of universe, [this interview](http://www.bradpittpress.com/artint_05_totalfilm.php) with Director David Fincher strongly implies that they (he and Pitt) chose to put the glove into the scene specifically to [weird-out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weird%20out) the studio executives who'd stipulated that Pitt had to be shirtless twice in the film. Again, no *specific* sexual act was intimated:

> *“One of the studio’s issues with the material was how we were going to
>   handle the sex between Marla and Tyler,” says Fincher, whose trade-off
>   for the studio shelling out on Pitt’s dentistry [they paid for the
>   removable cap that ensured Tyler could have a chipped tooth] was that
>   the star would sometimes take his shirt off. He did it twice. One of
>   which was when he opens the door after sex with Marla—wearing a rubber
>   glove. “We had that take starred and sent over to Fox under the guise
>   of, ‘Look! Look how good he looks, he has his shirt off!’” laughs
>   Fincher. “I’ve learned that one way to control people is to give them
>   other things to worry about. If you’re worried that somebody is too
>   fearful you can either try to empower them or you can give them so
>   much to fear that they just don’t want to be around you. Either way
>   you’ve sort of neutralized them!”*

Answer (score 7):

Marla isn't a fragment of Jack's imagination first of all, that's a false theory. Secondly, there isn't a true reason for the glove. It was improvised by Brad Pitt for comedic effect. Truly, it's that simple.

From the [Triva section of the movie on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137523/trivia?ref_=tt_ql_2):

> When Tyler (Brad Pitt) catches The Narrator (Edward Norton) listening
>   at the door as he has sex with Marla (Helena Bonham Carter), he is
>   wearing a rubber glove. This was Brad Pitt's idea, and caused a great
>   deal of controversy with President of Production at Fox 2000 Pictures,
>   Laura Ziskin. She was horrified when she saw the scene and demanded
>   that it be removed. However at a subsequent test screening, the
>   appearance of the glove got the biggest laugh of the whole movie,
>   prompting Ziskin to change her mind.

Comment: In the commentary, Pitt states that it was his idea and that it was improvised.